# Parsing my json file by using grok pattern in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse json file into elasticsearch by using logstash but I couldn't , I guess that I need to write some grok pattern. But I couldn't. How can I send below json into elasticsearch by using logstash.

{"machinename":"test1",

"longdate":"2019-01-29 13:19:32",

"level":"Error",

"mysite":"test1",

"message":"test2",

"exception":"test3",

"timestamp":"2019-01-29T13:19:32.257Z"
}

My logstash file:

```
input {
  file {
       path => ["P:/logs/*.txt"]
        start_position => "beginning" 
        discover_interval => 10
        stat_interval => 10
        sincedb_write_interval => 10
        close_older => 10
       codec => multiline { 
        negate => true
        what => "previous" 
       }
  }
}

filter {  
 date {
            match => ["TimeStamp", "ISO8601"]
             }  
    json{
        source => "request"
        target => "parsedJson"

    }   

}   

output {  

    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }



    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
         index => "log-%{+YYYY.MM}"

    }   
}
```

ERROR:

[2019-01-29T14:30:54,907][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-01-29T14:30:56,929][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.2"}
[2019-01-29T14:30:59,167][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 12, column 18 (byte 281) after input {\n  file {\n\t   path => [\"P:/logs/*.txt\"]\n\t\tstart_position => \"beginning\" \n\t\tdiscover_interval => 10\n\t\tstat_interval => 10\n\t\tsincedb_write_interval => 10\n\t\tclose_older => 10\n       codec => multiline { \n\t\tpattern => \"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\\"\n\t\tnegate => true\n        what => \"", :backtrace=>["P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in`compile_graph'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in`map'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:49:in`initialize'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:167:in `initialize'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in`execute'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:305:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-01-29T14:31:00,417][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-01-29T14:34:23,554][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-01-29T14:34:24,554][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.2"}
[2019-01-29T14:34:27,486][ERROR][logstash.codecs.multiline] Missing a required setting for the multiline codec plugin:

codec {
    multiline {
      pattern => # SETTING MISSING
      ...
    }
  }
[2019-01-29T14:34:27,502][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:89:in `config_init'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/base.rb:19:in`initialize'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/plugin_factory.rb:97:in `plugin'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:110:in`plugin'", "(eval):8:in `<eval>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in`eval'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:82:in `initialize'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:167:in`initialize'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in `execute'", "P:/elk/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:305:in`block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-01-29T14:34:27,971][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

Comment: Your multiline codec is missing the `pattern` option. In your use case, it should look like `"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\\"\\}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use the [json filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json) for logstash.

This way the filter plugin in logstash will parse the json:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

Another thing good to have is the tag_on_failure. this way, if the json it's not valid or misunderstood, you will see the message in elasticsearch/kibana, but with the _jsonparsefailure tag.

```
  filter {
      json {
        source => "message"
        tag_on_failure => [ "_jsonparsefailure" ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: I checked my json by using "https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ " . It looks good. Do I need grok pattern?

Comment: no you don't. grok it's a filter plugin, json is also a filter plugin. You don't need to use both in this example. Just the json. And then you can see the result in elasticsearch if everything goes well.

Comment: I think " pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\|"" creates a problem. I have to remove it but It creates missing error.

Comment: I removed grok . And It created above error.Please Can you look at "ERROR:" part?